# Alert message from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, code-behind, scriptmanager

Is there any other way to display alert message from back end in asp.net web application rather than this.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alertMessage","alert('Called from code-behind directly!');", true);
```

I have included using `System.Web.UI` namespace also, but still am getting these 2 errors with this code:

First error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(System.Web.UI.Page,
>   System.Type, string, string, bool)' has some invalid
>   arguments D:\my_backup\Demos\NewShop\NewShop\API\ProductAPIController.cs
>   85    17  N‌​ewShop

Second error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'NewShop.API.ProductAPIController' to
>   'System.Web.UI.Page'
>   D:\my_backup\Demos\NewShop\NewShop\API\ProductAPIController‌​.cs  85  53
>   NewShop

Comment: What is wrong with this?

Comment: What error is there with this code? What doesn't work as expected? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @up-voter : I don't think the question is worth for  +1

Comment: `Response.Write("<script>alert('another way to display the alert message');</script>");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages tell you what is wrong. The `RegisterStartupScript` method requires a first argument of type `System.Web.UI.Page`, which is used in ASP.NET WebForms. Instead you are passing `this` as the first argument, which is a `Controller` class, which is used in ASP.NET MVC!

That means the code you are using is meant for another web architecture. To control JavaScript output from a Controller, you are much better off using the `Model` or maybe `ViewBag`. Like this:

**In your controller code**

```
ViewBag.ShowAlert = true;
```

**In your view**

```
@if (ViewBag.ShowAlert)
{
    <script>alert("(Almost) called from code-behind");</script>
}
```

If you need full control over the script that is rendered, save the script as a string in the ViewBag, even though this is definitely not recommended!

**In your controller code**

```
ViewBag.SomeScript = "alert('Added by the controller');";
```

**In your view**

```
@if (ViewBag.SomeScript != null)
{
    <script>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SomeScript)</script>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for other way then here it is

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Called from code-behind directly!');</script>");
```

> **Note :**     However this is not the good way. You'll never know where your code will be inserted. Also it could potentially break HTML
>   and cause `Javascript` errors. `RegisterClientScriptBlock` is right
>   way to run `Javascript` on client.